# Why is my SVN telling me that my copy is too old all of a sudden?

Tags: svn, version-control

My SVN just started acting funny today for some reason. I'm using textmate 2, and when I try to check in I get this error:

[image]

I haven't updated svn or anything, and I'm still able to check things out, I just can't commit any changes or add anything. I have my OS and Xcode updated to the newest version.

Also, on a related note, I did a fresh checkout, and it is telling me that some of the files aren't added into the SVN and some of them are giving me a red x icon which I'm not sure what it means exactly, but I've seen the icon once before and it seems to have the effect that SVN won't touch that file.

[image: Here's what the X looks like]

Answer (score 2):

> I have my OS and Xcode updated to the newest version.

The version of Subversion bundled in XCode is newer than the one that Textmate is calling. IOW, you have two Subversion clients installed and when XCode touched the working copy, it upgraded it to the latest format.

You need to find the copy of Subversion that Textmate is using and upgrade it, remove it, or move it lower in your `PATH` than the one XCode is using.